# Display a list in a scrollable gallery

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I'm learning ASP.NET and have to make a movie website similar to the one on MSDN for MVC but a bit more intricate and using regular ASP.NET instead of MVC

I want to use a function that returns a List from my database with all of movies and their information and then display the image and title properties in a scrollable gallery.

What I've been trying and having trouble with doing is running a loop over the generic list and appending the desired properties for each item to an unordered list element and then using CSS and Javascript to display that as a gallery.

Is there an elegant or easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of free component/controls that designed for your purpose. you can pass items and properties to them and they do the rest with elegant view.
Most of them uses jquery, 
take a loot at:
[15 Amazing jQuery Image Gallery/Slideshow Plugins and Tutorials](http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/)